# Use a Decimal Value as a Hexadecimal Value

Tags: c#, hex, decimal

I have the int `15` (or the string `"15"`, that's just as easy), and I need to use it to create the value:

```
"\u0015"
```

Is there some conversion which would accomplish this?  I can't do this:

```
"\u00" + myInt.ToString()
```

Because the first literal is invalid.  Is there a simple way to get this result?

(If you're curious, this is for integrating with a hardware device where the vendor sometimes expresses integer values as hexadecimal.  For example, I'd need to send today's date to the device as `"\u0015\u0010\u0002"`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Given that you want a Unicode code point of 21, not 15, you should definitely start with the string "15". If you try to start with 15 as an `int`, you'll find you can't express anything with a hex representation involving A-F...

So, given "15" the simplest way of parsing that as hex is probably:

```
string text = "15";
int codePoint = Convert.ToInt32(text, 16);
```

After that, you just need to cast to `char`:

```
string text = "15";
int codePoint = Convert.ToInt32(text, 16);
char character = (char) codePoint;
```

Note that this will only work for code points in the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) - i.e. U+0000 to U+FFFF. If you need to handle values beyond that (e.g. [U+1F601](http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/1F601)) then you should use `char.ConvertFromUtf32` instead:

```
string text = "15";
int codePoint = Convert.ToInt32(text, 16);
string character = char.ConvertFromUtf32(codePoint);
```

Answer (score 2):

Unicode literals in strings are resolved at compile-time, that's why `"\u00" + myInt.ToString()` doesn't work (the `ToString()` and concatenation are evaluated at runtime).

You could cast the int to char:

```
int unicodeCodePoint = 15; // or 21
char c = (char)unicodeCodePoint;
```

Comment: @JonSkeet: `"It's a bit messed up..."` - On that we completely agree.  Vendors, though.  What can you do?  :)